# Return field value when referencing model instance

Tags: django

If I have the following Model:

```
class VATPercentage(models.Model):
     percentage = models.IntegerField(default=21)
```

Is there anyway I can make it so that when you reference an instance of it, you actually get the value stored in the **percentage** field?

For example, I want to be able to do: `Service.vat_percentage` instead of `Service.vat_percentage.percentage`

Similar to how _ *str* _ would work if you called str() on the model, but I need an integer..

I tried to look for something similar like defining an _ *int* _ function but i dont think thats a thing..

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some confusion with your data modelling here. I understand your current data model to look something like:

```py
class VATPercentage(models.Model):
     percentage = models.IntegerField(default=21)

class Service(models.Model):
    vat_percentage = models.ForeignKey('VATPercentage', cascade=models.SET_NULL)
    # probably other fields here
```

If you want the actual value to be an attribute of Service, I think it just shows you should set up your `Service` model like so:

```py
class Service(models.Model):
    percentage = models.IntegerField(default=21)
```

and get rid of `VATPercentage` entirely.

If that's really not possible, then you can either:

- annotate the queryset e.g:

```py
service = Service.objects.annotate(vat_percentage_value=F('vat_percentage__percentage')).first()
service.vat_percentage_value  # will be the integer value
```

- or define a property on the model:

```py
class Service(models.Model):
    vat_percentage = models.ForeignKey('VATPercentage', cascade=models.SET_NULL)
    # probably other fields here

    @property
    def vat_percentage_value(self):
        return self.vat_percentage.percentage
```

I would strongly discourage those two options if you don't need the `VATPercentage` model for anything else. Also note I used a different name `vat_percentage_value` on purpose to avoid *shadowing* the name of the ForeignKey field.

A last couple notes:

- I would probably use a FloatField instead of an IntegerField here, it's reasonable to assume you might not always have whole numbers for that value.
- Yes, the `__int__()` [method can be defined](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__) to implement what the built-in `int()` function returns when passed the object. Probably not what you want here though :)

Answer (score -1):

I think, thats impossible. If in Left side of `=` you have **instance**, then  Right side will have only **instance** and nothing more, not str or int! Let's try (assume we have any simple Car model):

```
>>> from app.models import Car
>>> inst = Car.objects.first()
>>> inst
<Car: Mazeratti>
>>> type(inst)
<class 'app.models.Car'>
```

So if you assign variable to object in your code, your variable will contain `object` but not string.

`__str__` used in template for  object, so if you send <Car: Mazeratti> object to template, django 'known' what need to do: show what you write in **str** method, i.e. `mazeratti`.

I hope I explained clearly))